# Drupal7 - How to select records from mysql in page?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

While i'm creating basic page in drupal i select **text format** to **PHP code**. Now I can write PHP code here.

I want to list records from MySQL, How can I include a database-connection here?

Is it good way writing PHP code in content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly call drupal api functions like `db_query()` without adding any `dbconection` in a page. Adding php codes inside a page is not recommented, try to create your own module for that or use views

Comment: @berkes it all depends on the requirements , isnt it?WHat if he needs a static select query requirement?

Comment: «Only very simple queries should use the static query mechanism. You should use a dynamic query if you need more complex queries, dynamic query generation or alterability.» from http://drupal.org/node/310072#query-options

Answer (score 0):

First: you should not use the PHP-input format. The fact that it is there is highly debated in Drupal, with many people leaning towards removing it entirely. It is both a security nightmare and a maintanance-horror.

That said, the PHP you are looking for is:

```
<?php
// Create an object of type SelectQuery
$query = db_select('users', 'u');

// Add extra detail to this query object: a condition, fields and a range
$query->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>');
$query->fields('u', array('uid', 'name', 'status', 'created', 'access'));
$query->range(0, 50);
?>
```

More on [dynamic queries](https://drupal.org/node/310075) is found on Drupal.org. No need to set-up your database, Drupal already handled that.

In case you want your code to connect to a differnt database then the main Drupal-database, you can either add that database to your settings.php:

```
$databases['gallery']['gallery'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'gallery',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'secret',
  'host' => 'localhost',
);
```

This introduces a new [database](https://drupal.org/node/310071) resource called "gallery" using a database "gallery". Useful when you want to use resources from another database, like records from a "gallery application".

You can then query that database using the key in the `$options`-parameter, like so:

```
<?php
// Create an object of type SelectQuery
$query = db_select('pictures', 'p', array('target' => 'gallery'));

// Add extra detail to this query object: a condition, fields and a range
$query->condition('p.status', 'published', '=');
$query->fields('p', array('path', 'title', 'date'));
$query->range(0, 50);
?>
```

Comment: If the requirements can be met through views, then no need of writing complex queries. A lot can be achieved using views itself.

Comment: OP is not asking for Views. However, Views has a lot of downsides too, learning and using simple PHP and queries gives a lot more freedom, flexibility, friendlier code, revision-control, deployment-ease and so on. As such they should always be considered as an option.

Comment: I just said, just because OP had mentioned that 'I want to list records from MySQL'